# Symfony Form - one class for standalone form and as a part other form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have Symfony form type class and I want use them standalone and as a part of other form. My class looks this:

```
class PracownikType extends AbstractType
{

    const DATA_CLASS = 'AppBundle\Entity\Pracownik';

    /** @var IPracownikRepository */
    private $pracownikRepository;

    /** @var User */
    private $user;

    /**
     * PracownikType constructor.
     * @param IPracownikRepository $pracownikRepository
     * @param TokenStorage $tokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(IPracownikRepository $pracownikRepository, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->pracownikRepository = $pracownikRepository;
        $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('imie', 'text')
            ->add('nazw', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'text')
            ->add('iloscDniWolnych', 'integer')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'class' => self::DATA_CLASS,
            'choices' => $this->pracownikRepository->findAllByUser($this->user),
            'choice_label' => 'getNazw'
        ]);
    }


    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pracownik';
    }

}
```

I wand use this class to create standalone form:

```
$form = $this->createForm('pracownik', $this->dodajPracownikaCommand);
```

And part of other form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('pracownik', 'pracownik');
}
```

How can I do this? Please help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of just using the string 'pracownik', create an instance like `new PracownikType()`.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('pracownik', new PracownikType());
}
```

if you must use the string you have to declare your form type as a service. See this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services

I don't recommend that at this time however as Symfony 2.8 is deprecating that type of behavior I think.

Comment: Hello, I declared this form type as a service - it's not a problem.

Comment: The syntax for defining form types as services is changing for 3.0 but the concept stays the same.  In fact, with 3.0 even the passing of a form type as an instance is going away.  Lots of code to change. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md#form